# Get-VPNConnection shows wrong connection status?

Tags: powershell, vpn

I'm setting up a script to monitor a VPN connection on a remote server, but the ConnectionStatus shows 'Disconnected', even though I know it currently is connected. Is there something I'm missing that would cause it to show the wrong status?

Using this:

```
Get-VpnConnection "<VPN Connection>" -CimSession <ServerName> -AllUserConnection
```

does return data about the VPN connection, but it shows Disconnected when it's connected.

We need it to give us the correct status because we'll have something in place to re-connect the VPN if it becomes disconnected. It won't do us any good if it's always showing up as disconnected.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue and am looking forward to a proper answer.

In the meantime, as a workaround you could parse the output of the `rasdial` command:

```
$vpnStatus = If ((rasdial | select-string "<VPN Connection>").count -eq 0) {"Disconnected"} else {"Online"}
```

Comment: It looks like this actually works for my purpose. At least it's reporting "Online" while it's connected. Thanks!